# Why does Ruby seem to access files in a directory randomly?

Tags: ruby, dir

Is this by design?

Here's the code:

```
class FileRenamer
    def RenameFiles(folder_path)    
        files = Dir.glob(folder_path + "/*")
    end
end

puts "Renaming files..."

renamer = FileRenamer.new()
files = renamer.RenameFiles("/home/papuccino1/Desktop/Test")
puts files

puts "Renaming complete."
```

It seems to be fetching the files is random order, not as they are displayed in Nautilus.

[image]

Is this by design? I'm just curious.

Comment: Does it alphabetically on my system (OS X). How does it display on yours?

Comment: Randomly. I have a test.txt, test (copy1).txt, test (copy2).text and they appear in random order.

Comment: Are you *sure* they are in random order? What statisitical analysis did you perform to verify that they are, in fact, random? My guess would rather be that they are in inode order which is anything but random.

Answer (score 14):

The order should be the same every time on a particular OS, however it *is* different across operating systems.

The behaviour or Dir.glob can not be relied upon to be the same across different OSs. Not sure if this is by design, but rather an artefact of the filesystems.

On Windows and Linux the results are sorted by hierarchy, and then alphabetically; On Mac OS X the results are sorted alphabetically.

You could mitigate the effect by calling sort on your results e.g.:

```
files = Dir.glob("./*").sort
```

or if you wanted it case insensitive, perhaps:

```
 files = Dir.glob("./*").sort {|a,b| a.upcase <=> b.upcase}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Scott is out of date.  I ran Dir.glob on Mac OS 10.15.6 Catalina, and the files were not returned in alphabetical order.  According to the ruby docs, the ordering is determined by the OS.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Dir.html

> Note that the pattern is not a regexp, it's closer to a shell glob. See File.fnmatch for the meaning of the flags parameter. Case sensitivity depends on your system (File::FNM_CASEFOLD is ignored), as does the order in which the results are returned.