# How would I iterate through this collection in a Ruby-esque way

Tags: ruby, iteration

```
puts "Renaming files..."

folder_path = "/home/papuccino1/Desktop/Test"
files = Dir.glob(folder_path + "/*").sort
extension = File.extname(files[0])
puts File.basename(files[0], extension)

puts "Renaming complete."
```

My end goal: Grab each file name in the folder and rename the file to Title Case:

```
input:                       output:
test.txt                     Text.txt
this is just a test.doc      This Is Just A Test.doc
The Final test is near.xls   The Final Test Is Near.xls
```

How would I iterate through each item in 'files'?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show how you can iterate through your files in a rubyish way:

```
Dir.glob(folder_path + "/*").sort.each do |f|
  # do something like:
  puts File.basename(f, File.extname(f))
end
```

Note that you can use either the *each* or *map* method. The difference between the two is that each returns your initial collection, while map returns the modified collection.

Comment: @Jakub: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529895/why-does-ruby-seem-to-access-files-in-a-directory-randomly

Comment: @Jakub: I am just doing what the OP wants. Why?

Comment: Before the edit you were iterating with `.sort`. That is *not* the correct way to do it. After the edit it's OK.

Comment: @Jacub: Ah yeah sure I forgot to apply each(..) before the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

a typical way is to use `each`

```
files.each do |file|
  p file
end
```

to see the filenames first and then add your renaming method.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dir.glob( File.join(".","*") ).select{|x| test(?f,x)}.sort.each | path |
   puts File.basename(x,File.extname(x)).split("\s").map(&:capitalize).join("\s") 
end
```

Comment: The `.select` there isn't exactly eficient.

Comment: @Jakub. so what do you suggest?

Comment: Do the test in the each loop.

Comment: any benchmarks? If you can convince me, I may change the answer.

Comment: I'm a bit lazy for that. Also depends on the probability of `test` passing - if it returns false for 90% of the input then this might be actually faster - save time on the nlog(n) of the sort. But otherwise you're doing an extra loop.

Comment: so the reasoning is there is an extra loop, not because the `select` method itself is inefficient. arguably, I can say that i don't have to test for file in the each loop as well. Until there is empirical benchmark results, i will have to disagree to agree

Comment: Okay, okay, here goes. Keep in mind that the actual numbers or probabilistic though depending on the probability of the test passing.

Comment: `data = (1..1000000).to_a.shuffle; Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|; bm.report("select") { data.select{|a| a % 17 != 0 }.sort.each{|a| a * 2} }; bm.report("no select") { data.sort.each{|a| a * 2 if a % 17 != 0 } };end`

Comment: Yields: `                user     system      total        real
select      0.550000   0.000000   0.550000 (  0.550148)
no select   0.460000   0.000000   0.460000 (  0.460014)`
`