# How to Test Factories First with Minitest but without the spec framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot, minitest

I found a blog post about [Testing Factories First](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/10/test-factories-first.html) (by BigBinary - which happens to be a Minitest/spec version of [Thoughtbot's RSpec original](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/testing-your-factories-first)).

Could you please show me the equivalent **without** the `spec` framework - just with Minitest (Rails)?

## The Thoughtbot approach (RSpec)

**spec/factories_spec.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.factories.map(&:name).each do |factory_name|
  describe "The #{factory_name} factory" do
     it 'is valid' do
      build(factory_name).should be_valid
     end
  end
end
```

**Rakefile**

```
if defined?(RSpec)
  desc 'Run factory specs.'
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:factory_specs) do |t|
    t.pattern = './spec/factories_spec.rb'
  end
end

task spec: :factory_specs
```

## The BigBinary approach (Minitest, spec)

**spec/factories_spec.rb**

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/spec_helper')

describe FactoryGirl do
  EXCEPTIONS = %w(base_address base_batch bad_shipping_address)
  FactoryGirl.factories.each do |factory|
    next if EXCEPTIONS.include?(factory.name.to_s)
    describe "The #{factory.name} factory" do

      it 'is valid' do
        instance = build(factory.name)
        instance.must_be :valid?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/tasks/factory.rake**

```
desc 'Run factory specs.'
Rake::TestTask.new(:factory_specs) do |t|
  t.pattern = './spec/factories_spec.rb'
end

task test: :factory_specs
```

What is the Minitest equivalent (without `spec`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I am presenting below is slightly different than the two original solutions - in the sense that my approach creates only one test, within which I cycle through the factories and run an assertion against each. I was not able to create a solution that mimics the original solutions any closer - which is (I believe) a separate test method for each factory. If someone could show such an implementation, that would be cool.

**test/aaa_factories_tests/factories_test.rb**

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper.rb')

class FactoriesTest < Minitest::Unit::TestCase

  puts "\n*** Factories Test ***\n\n"

  EXCEPTIONS = %w(name_of_a_factory_to_skip another_one_to_skip)

  def test_factories

    FactoryGirl.factories.each do |factory|

      next if EXCEPTIONS.include?(factory.name.to_s)

      instance = FactoryGirl.build(factory.name)
      assert instance.valid?, "invalid factory: #{factory.name}, error messages: #{instance.errors.messages.inspect}"

      instance = factory = nil
    end         
  end   
end
```

Thanks to the way `Minitest` [works out of the box](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails#usage) -- *add any directories under `test/` and `minitest-rails` will automatically create the associated rake task for it. So let's say you add a `test/api/` directory, `rake minitest:api` will automagically be available.* -- I see the task when I run `bundle exec rake -T` with no other configurations:

```
rake minitest:aaa_factories_tests    # Runs tests under test/aaa_factories_tests
```

And I am able to run this task successfully:

```
-bash> bundle exec rake minitest:aaa_factories_tests

*** Factories Test ***

Run options: --seed 19208

# Running tests:

.

Finished tests in 0.312244s, 3.2026 tests/s, 9.6079 assertions/s.

1 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Despite the ugliness of prepending the directory with `aaa`, I am able to have the factories tested first with:

```
bundle exec rake minitest:all
```

The reason for the *aaa prepend* solution is [`MiniTest` does a `Dir` `glob`](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails/blob/master/lib/minitest/rails/testing.rb#L21) and on `Mac OS X` (and other Unix variants) the results are sorted alphabetically ([though the results differ across different platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529895/why-does-ruby-seem-to-access-files-in-a-directory-randomly)).

As well, I prepended [the `default_tasks` array](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails/blob/master/lib/minitest/rails/testing.rb#L17) with `aaa_factories_tests` to have the factories tested first in *the default `Minitest` task* (i.e. when running `bundle exec rake minitest`).

**lib/tasks/factories_first.rake**

```
MiniTest::Rails::Testing.default_tasks.unshift('aaa_factories_tests') if Rails.env =~ /^(development|test)\z/
```

Note that the above condition avoids erroneously referencing `Minitest` in environments where it is unavailable (I have confined `minitest-rails` to `:test` and `:development` groups in `Gemfile`). Without this `if`-condition, pushing to Heroku (for example to `staging` or `production`) will result in `uninitialized constant MiniTest`.

Of course I am also able to run the factories test directly:

```
bundle exec ruby -I test test/aaa_factories_tests/factories_test.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for MiniTest without the spec framework:

**test/factories_test.rb**

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/test_helper')

class FactoriesTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  EXCEPTIONS = %w(griddler_email)
  FactoryBot.factories.map(&:name).each do |factory_name|
    next if factory_name.to_s.in?(EXCEPTIONS)
    context "The  #{factory_name} factory" do
      should 'be valid' do
        factory = build(factory_name)
        assert_equal true, factory.valid?, factory.errors.full_messages
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/tasks/factory.rake**

```
namespace :test do
  desc 'Test factories'
  Rake::TestTask.new(:factories) do |t|
    t.pattern = './test/factories_test.rb'
  end
end

task minitest: 'test:factories'
```

The most important thing is to use **taks minitest** instead of **task test** if you want the factories tests to be run before other tests.